# How can I iterate a dataframe from another one on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a program that will go through a Excel file that contains meteorological data and make several smaller files with a subset of this larger file. The file has the parameter 'EstacaoCodigo' separated in batches so the idea the code is to check if a row has the same parameter, if so add this row to a temporary dataframe and if not to export the dataframe and go to the next parameter.

`planilha_1 = pd.read_excel("Excel")`

The next code is a attempt at building this temporary dataframe.

```
est = planilha_1.loc[0,'EstacaoCodigo']
ind = 0
planilha_temp = planilha_1.loc[[ind]]
while est == planilha_1.loc[ind,'EstacaoCodigo']:
  planilha_temp = pd.concat([planilha_temp,planilha_1[ind]],axis=0)
  ind = ind + 1
planilha_temp
```

If I use the concat function without the brackets on the original dataframe ( `planilha_1[ind]`),
the code simply merges the two dataframes, and if I use the term I get the following error. How can I iterate this temporary dataframe?

```
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: maybe you should use `iloc` instead of `loc` - because `loc` uses values from `index` and you may not have value/key `0` in index. `iloc` doesn't use value from `index` but it counts rows on its own.

Comment: Hello furas, I tried using iloc and got the same error message (KeyError: 0), also the dataframe does have a 0 index.

Comment: `pd.read_excel` does read the data, so you really need to show sufficient data for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: maybe create minimal working code with example data - so we could run it and see problem. And you should show FULL error message - it may have other useful information. And it should show which line in your code makes problem. You can also use `print()` to see what you have in variables before line which makes problem. Maybe this line works with some part of DF without index `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select from the origina dataframe all the rows that have your required value as follows:

```
est = planilha_1.loc[0,'EstacaoCodigo']
planilha_temp=planilha_1[planilha_1['EstacaoCodigo']==est].reset_index(drop=True)
```